# Osmfilter - filter every node with at least one tag

Tags: openstreetmap, osmfilter

I'm using osm data and the `osmfilter` tool but I can't achieve to filter all nodes with at least one tag. I want to drop nodes with no tags.

My approch is:

```bash
osmfilter DataOSM.o5m --keep-nodes= --keep-tags="*=" -o=test.osm
```

But it does not work. All nodes are kept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the author of the tool, now I have something:

```
osmfilter input.o5m --keep="*=" -o=output.osm
```

All nodes, ways and relations with at least one tag but as well nodes without tags that belongs to a way/relation with a tag. To drop these nodes as well use:

```
osmfilter input.o5m --keep="*=" --ignore-dependencies -o=output.osm
```